# Apply map combination - not working as I expect

Tags: clojure, mapreduce

In repl addition accross vectors works as expected

```
> (map + [1 2 3] [1 2 3])
(2 4 6)
```

But what I have is a vector of vectors and when I try

```
> (apply #(map + %) [[1 2 3] [1 2 3]])
ArityException Wrong number of args (2) passed to: user$eval14$fn clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity (AFn.java:437)
```

How do I add corresponding numbers in vector of vector?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just one step from your first example:

```
user> (apply map + [[1 2 3] [1 2 3]])
(2 4 6)
```

Comment: (apply map + [[1 2 3] [1 2 3]])
is more straitforward than (apply (partial map +) [[1 2 3] [1 2 3]]).

Comment: Neat, that's much more straightforward than using `partial`!

Answer (score 0):

The reader macro approach can work with:

```
(user=> (apply #(map + % %2) [[1 2 3] [1 2 3]])
(2 4 6)
```

It requires that you know how many vectors are in the vector, and specify each arg.  If the 'apply' approach works for you, it will be more flexible going forward, like in:

```
user=> (apply map + [[1 2 3] [1 2 3] [1 2 3]])
(3 6 9)
```